# Error 450 when use AcroExch.AVdoc.Open to open pdf file using vba

Tags: excel, pdf, acrobat, vba

I'm writing a macro to search specific texts (more than ten words) in some pdf documents, using Excel 2013 and Adobe Acrobat XI, reference: Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library.

I found this code online begins

```
Sub findtext()
  'Initialize Acrobat by creating App object
  Set PDFApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")

  'Set AVDoc object
  Set PDFDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")

  'PDF path
  PDFPath = "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\text.pdf"

  'Open the PDF
  PDFDoc.Open(PDFPath)

  ......

END Sub
```

Run the code line by line. the first three lines Work fine.

When at line *PDFDoc.Open(PDFPath)*, it returns ***Error 450*** Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

I searched online, Acrobat forum, Stackoverflow, you name it... and could not find an answer...

Does anyone else run into this problem before?

I'm curious why it happens and how to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code and see if you can resolve the error.

PDFDoc.Open PDFPath, ""

Comment: PDFDoc.Open(PDFPath, "") also works. seems like can't ignore ""